# Why is my brick texture fading after I bake it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, baking

[image: Before Bake]

[image: After Bake]

The Image size is 4096x4096 so it's not a low-quality issue.

Comment: What is it we are seeing there? In the second screenshot the material seems to be the same as in the first screenshot. So where did the baked image go, how does it look? And do I get this correctly that although the material is the same and the baked image is not used anywhere, the appearance of the tiles is different?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the second picture is the baked texture, I just hadn't clicked off of  the brick texture